# Swing - drawString shifting animation fails

Tags: java, swing, animation

I'm trying to make a little animation on Java swing, which should move the drawString's string a little to left(to center), however, whenever I try to do it, the program just slowly opens and just jumps to the place where It should land eventually, so seemingly, there no animation occurs.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GradientPaint;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.RenderingHints;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.border.Border;

public class IntroPanel extends JPanel {

private int x = 300;
private JButton exitButton, startButton;
private JPanel buttonsPanel;

public IntroPanel()
{
    setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300, 150));
    setLayout( new BorderLayout());

    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    exitButton = new JButton( "Exit" );
    startButton = new JButton( "Start" );

    exitButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    startButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /**
             * TODO GOES TO MAIN PANEL
             */
        }
    });

    setBackground( new Color( 250, 250, 250) );
    startButton.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(70, 40) );
    exitButton.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(70, 40) );
    Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 25, 0);
    setBorder(padding);
    buttonsPanel.setBackground( new Color( 250, 250, 250));
    buttonsPanel.add(startButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(exitButton);
    add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    animate();
}

public void animate()
{
    for( int i = 1; i < 211; i++ )
    {
        x--;

        repaint();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) { }
    }
}

public void paintComponent( Graphics page )
{
    Graphics2D gra = (Graphics2D) page;

    gra.setFont( new Font( "Philosopher-BoldItalic", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 50 ) );

    Color start = new Color( 50, 50, 50 );
    Color end = new Color( 250, 250, 250 );

    GradientPaint gradient = 
            new GradientPaint( 120, 100, start, 270, 270, end);

    gra.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    gra.setPaint( gradient );

    gra.drawString("Geometrica", x, 100);
 }
}
```

Main method:

```
    public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Geometrica" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(420, 250);
        frame.setBackground( new Color(250, 250, 250) );

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.getContentPane().add( new IntroPanel() );
        frame.setVisible(true);
       }
     }
```

Thank you!

Comment: @OP: When does `animate` return?

Comment: `Thread.sleep(10);` Don't block the EDT (Event Dispatch Thread).  The GUI will 'freeze' when that happens.  See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for details and the fix.

Comment: @AndrewThompson he's not blocking the EDT... he's just *not making the window visible* until after the animation is done.

Comment: For better help sooner, post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example) or [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example).

Comment: @VerumInfiniti  I'm not sure what it is you appreciate, but (shrugs) .. you're welcome.

Comment: @AndrewThompson for your interest and for your altruism its better than just don't caring about someone who really needs help :)

Comment: Well.. if you really want to solve this, follow my advice and post a single piece of runnable code I/we can experiment with.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I'm currently working on concurrency though, Its been couple of months since I started this programming things so I'm trying to learn those concepts and I will do some experiments later on and post it here

Comment: Cool.  Let me know in a comment when you are ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call the animate method after the frame is made visible from outside the object.

Also you need to call `super.paintComponent(page);` inside your `animate` method like it says in the Javadoc then you'll get the desired result.
Main:

```
public class Main {

      public static void main(String[] args) {   
        JFrame frame = new JFrame( "Geometrica" );
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        frame.setSize(420, 250);
        frame.setBackground( new Color(250, 250, 250) );

        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        IntroPanel p=new IntroPanel();
        frame.getContentPane().add(p);
        frame.setVisible(true);
        p.animate();        

       }
}
```

IntroPanel:

```
public class IntroPanel extends JPanel {

private int x = 300;
private JButton exitButton, startButton;
private JPanel buttonsPanel;

public IntroPanel()
{
    setPreferredSize( new Dimension( 300, 150));
    setLayout( new BorderLayout());

    buttonsPanel = new JPanel();
    exitButton = new JButton( "Exit" );
    startButton = new JButton( "Start" );

    exitButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    });

    startButton.addActionListener( new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            /**
             * TODO GOES TO MAIN PANEL
             */
        }
    });

    setBackground( new Color( 250, 250, 250) );
    startButton.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(70, 40) );
    exitButton.setPreferredSize( new Dimension(70, 40) );
    Border padding = BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(0, 0, 25, 0);
    setBorder(padding);
    buttonsPanel.setBackground( new Color( 250, 250, 250));
    buttonsPanel.add(startButton);
    buttonsPanel.add(exitButton);
    add(buttonsPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
}

public void animate()
{
    super.paintComponent(page);
    for( int i = 1; i < 211; i++ )
    {
        x--;

        repaint();

        try
        {
            Thread.sleep(10);
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ex) { }
    }
}

public void paintComponent( Graphics page )
{
    Graphics2D gra = (Graphics2D) page;

    gra.setFont( new Font( "Philosopher-BoldItalic", Font.ITALIC | Font.BOLD, 50 ) );

    Color start = new Color( 50, 50, 50 );
    Color end = new Color( 250, 250, 250 );

    GradientPaint gradient = 
            new GradientPaint( 120, 100, start, 270, 270, end);

    gra.setRenderingHint( RenderingHints.KEY_TEXT_ANTIALIASING, 
            RenderingHints.VALUE_TEXT_ANTIALIAS_ON);
    gra.setPaint( gradient );

    gra.drawString("Geometrica", x, 100);
 }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it is still slow and no animation occurs it just jumps to the middle directly, is there anything wrong with my for loop? I'm actually new to these stuff, therefore I don't figure out these errors easily.

Comment: Oh I got it! thank  you now it runs on my machine either, I've moved the super.paintComponent(page);'s place from animate() to actual paintComponent method then It worked fine! thanks!